# Making configuration node support both string and array in Symfony 2 configuration?

Tags: symfony, configuration, dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

Can my configuration node `source` support both `string` and `array` values?

Sourcing from `string`:

```
# Valid configuration 1
my_bundle:
    source: %kernel.root_dir%/../Resources/config/source.json
```

Sourcing from `array`:

```
# Valid configuration 2
my_bundle:
    source:
        operations: []
        commands: []
```

The extension class would be able to distinguish between them:

```php
if (is_array($config['source']) {
    // Bootstrap from array
} else {
    // Bootstrap from file
}
```

I might use something like this:

```php
$rootNode->children()
    ->variableNode('source')
        ->validate()
            ->ifTrue(function ($v) { return !is_string($v) && !is_array($v); })
            ->thenInvalid('Configuration value must be either string or array.')
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end();
```

But how ca I add constraints on the structure of `source` (operations, commands, etc...) to the variable node (that should only be enforced when its value is of type `array`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can use the config normalization by refactoring your extension.

In your extension change your code to check if a path is set

```
if ($config['path'] !== null) {
    // Bootstrap from file.
} else {
    // Bootstrap from array.
}
```

And allow the user to use a string for config.

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('source')
            ->beforeNormalization()
            ->ifString()
                ->then(function($value) { return array('path' => $value); })
            ->end()
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('foo')
                // ...
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

Like this you can allow the user to use a string or an array which can be validate.

See the [symfony documentation for normalisation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/config/definition.html#normalization)

Hope it's helpful.
Best regard.

Comment: Not bad. I should handle the case when `path` and `operations` and `commands` are setted. +1 for me

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use a [variable node](https://github.com/symfony/Config/blob/master/Definition/Builder/VariableNodeDefinition.php) type in combination with some custom validation logic:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException;

public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->variableNode('source')
                ->validate()
                    ->ifTrue(function ($v) {
                        return false === is_string($v) && false === is_array($v);
                    })
                    ->thenInvalid('Here you message about why it is invalid')
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();
    ;

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

This will succesfully process:

```
my_bundle:
    source: foo

# and

my_bundle:
    source: [foo, bar]
```

but it won't process:

```
my_bundle:
    source: 1

# or

my_bundle
    source: ~
```

Of course, you won't get the nice validation rules a normal configuration node will provide you and you won't be able to use those validation rules on the array (or string) passed but you will be able to validate the passed data in the closure used.

Comment: Yes, I've already used something like this. But this time the array node is very complex.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. Can't you use another structure like the one used by the JMSDiExtraBundle?